# How to fix "CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config" (aws-sdk) in react-native

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to access the "adminAddUserToGroup" method of AWS Cognito 
from my react-native application. I want to add a user to a specific group right after he registers.

The documentation of the method says "developer credentials required".
I have my credentials (AccessKey and SecretKey) in ~/.aws/credentials in my system. How do I use this in my code?

```
    var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider(
      { region: regionId }
    );
    const params = {
      GroupName: groupName,
      UserPoolId: userPoolId,
      Username: that.state.username
    };
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminAddUserToGroup(
      params,
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
          console.log(data);
        }
      }
    );
```

This causes the error

```
    CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config
at credError (blob:http://localhost:8081/6f586340-99cf-40d3-b978-de453021be50:245014:50)
at Config.getCredentials (blob:http://localhost:8081/6f586340-99cf-40d3-b978-de453021be50:245058:24)
at Request.VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS (blob:http://localhost:8081/6f586340-99cf-40d3-b978-de453021be50:245435:36)
at Request.callListeners (blob:http://localhost:8081/6f586340-99cf-40d3-b978-de453021be50:244218:28)
at Request.emit (blob:http://localhost:8081/6f586340-99cf-40d3-b978-de453021be50:244195:20)
at Request.emit (blob:http://localhost:8081/6f586340-99cf-40d3-b978-de453021be50:247081:26)
at Request.transition (blob:http://localhost:8081/6f586340-99cf-40d3-b978-de453021be50:246822:22)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (blob:http://localhost:8081/6f586340-99cf-40d3-b978-de453021be50:247182:22)
at Request.runTo (blob:http://localhost:8081/6f586340-99cf-40d3-b978-de453021be50:246894:27)
at Request.send (blob:http://localhost:8081/6f586340-99cf-40d3-b978-de453021be50:246887:22)
```

Where and how should I add the dev credentials?

Answer (score 1):

In react-Native the sdk won't have access to files on your system. You can set credentials in browser like this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html